# To separate functions or not to separate functions? That is the 

Tags: performance, coding-style, functional-programming, standards

At this point in time I am approaching the 1800 line mark in my code.

It contains a series of different forms and one big function which checks, validates, and determines the next step in the process. I have a total of 12 functions and I'ld like to know the programming philosophies and thoughts on whether or not (or when?) to separate the functions into their own file and when to leave them all on the same page.

Any thoughts on both your style of programming and any links to established programming standards of a particular group or philosophy of programming?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) book, a function needs to contain -one- logical unit, if it contains more than one, then break it into two functions. Another hint is if function name is too cumbersome or long. That too is a hint about a function that can be refactored.

Incidentally, Code Complete book should be on reading list of any serious software developer.

Comment: That looks like a great book, I'm lining up to purchase it.

Comment: It is big, 800+ pages long, but it is worth the effort. Plus once you read it one time it is very useful as reference book.